# AS3 component Slider not working when loaded from another swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a simple Flash application that uses a component Slider to increase or decrease the size of the text in a TextArea (ta). It works perfectly fine on its own, however, when I try to load the same swf file from another application, I get the following error...

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property fl.managers:IFocusManager::form not found 
on fl.managers.FocusManager and there is no default value. 

at fl.controls::Slider/thumbPressHandler()
```

AS3 code...

```
import fl.events.*;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

ta.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.color = 0xCCCCCC;
tf.font = "Trebuchet MS";
tf.size = 12;

slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, sliderChange);

style();

function style():void
{
    ta.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
}

function sliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
{
    tf.size = slider.value;
    ta.setStyle("textFormat", tf);
}
```

Could the containing swf file that I'm loading the slider swf file in anyway effect the slider application? I don't quite understand why it works on its own, but not when loaded from another app.

Comment: If you load the app from another, it does not have access to stage at its start. It can cause all kinds of problems. Apparently `FocusManager` wants stage to be available at its initialization. This might not be able to be circumvented, I don't yet see the way of retrieving Flash CS's default created `FocusManager` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem. I needed to add a component Slider to the library of the app I was loading the slider swf from.